# Alternatives to reference to parent class

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an `inf` file parser (windows drivers, in theory similar to infs, in reality quite different).

I have a parent `InfFile` class which contains the structured but unparsed data in the form of `Sections` and `Keys` (I call it unparsed because it's not been converted into anything more useful than just `Sections` and `Keys`, as oppose to the rest of the data that comes after), but also gives access to some parsed data, such as `SupportedOperatingSystems`, `Folders`, `Folder.Files` etc.

The problem I'm facing is that in `inf` file can reference 4 types of `Folders`: `default`, `X86`, `Ia64` and `Amd64`. So, it felt logical to me to try to shift all of the folder related code to a `InfFolders` class, with properties `Default`, `X86`, `Ia64` and `Amd64` (I can't simply merge them).

However, in order to figure out which folders are referenced in it, I need access to both the `Sections` and `Keys` properties of the `InfFile` class. That means either:

- my `InfFolders` class contains a reference to its parent (which I think is probably not the best solution),
- `InfFile` parses the data first and then passes it to the `InfFolders` as part of the constructor, but that means all of the `Folder` logic now lives in the `InfFile` class again,
- I pass the needed `Sections` and `Keys` to `InfFolders` as part of the constructor, and have the logic to sort them into usable objects in there.

What is the best way to do this and what is best practice in situations like this?

An idea of what the `InfFolders` class looks like is this:

```
public class InfFolders
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<InfSourceFolder> Default()
    {
        return GetFolders("SourceDiskNames").ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<InfSourceFolder> X86()
    {
        return GetFolders("SourceDiskNames.X86").ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<InfSourceFolder> Ia64()
    {
        return GetFolders("SourceDisksNames.Ia64").ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<InfSourceFolder> Amd64()
    {
        return GetFolders("SourceDisksNames.Amd64").ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    private IEnumerable<InfSourceFolder> GetFolders(string sectionName)
    {
        return <InfFile reference>[sectionName]?.Keys?.Select(
            x =>
                new InfSourceFolder(Convert.ToInt32(x.Name),
                    new FileInfo(<InfFile reference>.FilePath).DirectoryName + x.Values.ElementAtOrDefault(3)));
    }
}
```

As you can see in the method `GetFolders()` there are 2 places where a reference to the parent is needed.

I *could* shift all of this code to `InfClass` and remove the `InfFolders` class altogether, but don't think that makes for a very good model either. The way I see it is there 4 properties all relate to the same thing, so they should be grouped together.

Comment: Not talking about inheritance here.

Comment: Is that all the content of your class InfFolders ?

Comment: And what's wrong about this reference? (except it is not an interface)

Comment: You keep calling it "parent", but it's just a shared collection of data this class operates on. If you have two classes that operate on the same collection, you'll have to share it in _some_ way.

Comment: @CodeCaster isn't sharing the reference `InfFile` just going be like opening a can of worms? Bad code that ends up getting more confusing over time?